# Vba Issue in If Else Condition

Tags: vba, excel

```
Set ws1 = wb.Worksheets("MacroGeneratedReport")
LastRow = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
For i = LastRow To 1 Step -1
If ws1.Cells(i, "I").Value = "A" Or ws1.Cells(i, "I").Value = "B" Or 
 ws1.Cells(i, "I").Value = "C" Or ws1.Cells(i, "I").Value = "D" Or 
 ws1.Cells(i, "I").Value = "E" Or ws1.Cells(i, "I").Value = "F" Or 
 ws1.Cells(i, "I").Value = "Y" Then
 ws1.Cells(i, "AO").Value = ws1.Cells(i, "Y").Value
Else
 **ws1.Cells(i, "AO").Value = ws1.Cells(i, "AP").Value * ws1.Cells(i, "W").Value**
End If
Next i
```

In the above code, The bold highlighted "Else condition" gives runtime error, while the code is giving correct output and correct value according to the condition. Please suggest the necessary changes.

Comment: "gives runtime error" - of the millions of possible errors, which one is it giving you?  And what do you mean it is giving correct output?  If it is giving a runtime error, how can that be correct output?

Comment: And, out of curiosity, what are the values in cells AP1 and W1 of the "MacroGeneratedReport" worksheet?

Comment: The `ws1.Cells(i, "AO").Value = ws1.Cells(i, "AP").Value * ws1.Cells(i, "W").Value` will throw `Type mismatch (Error 13)` if one of the values in multiplication is not numeric.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is "Screaming" to use `Select Case` instead of your multiple `Or`s.

***Code***

```
Set ws1 = wb.Worksheets("MacroGeneratedReport")
With ws1
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = LastRow To 1 Step -1
        Select Case .Cells(i, "I").Value
            Case "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "Y"
                .Cells(i, "AO").Value = .Cells(i, "Y").Value

            Case Else
                ' check that both values are numeric
                If IsNumeric(.Cells(i, "AP").Value) And IsNumeric(.Cells(i, "W").Value) Then
                    .Cells(i, "AO").Value = .Cells(i, "AP").Value * .Cells(i, "W").Value
                End If            
        End Select
    Next i
End With
```

Comment: I bet that `1` should be `2`!

Comment: @YowE3K where exactly ?

Comment: In the `For` statement - that's the only way I can make sense of what the OP says about "the code is giving correct output and correct value" - I'm thinking that they are multiplying their headings together.

Comment: While this version looks better to the eye, I am pretty sure it will raise the same runtime error.

Comment: @GSerg it might, I hope the PO will let us know at what line, so we can try and find the cause for the error

Comment: @YowE3K opps, missed that one

Comment: Ooh - sneaky fix!!

Comment: @YowE3K LOL ;) very

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer, but you could simplify your code, without `Case` ;-)

```
If UCase(ws1.Cells(i, "I").Value) Like "[A-FY]" Then
```

(The `UCase` is not required if you have `Option Compare Text`)